# Question concerning cyclic modules and modules where the socle of $M$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, socle

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an $R$-module of finite length $n$ (given by the number of composition factors). I am trying to prove or disprove:

1. If $\mathrm{Soc}(M)$ (the socle of $M$) is a unique irreducible module, then $M$ is cyclic.
2. The converse statement to 1.
3. If $\mathrm{Soc}(M)$ and $M$ is cyclic and $M$ is of finite length, then every submodule of $M$ is cyclic and of finite length

I have been trying to prove/disprove these things but keep running around in circles. Would I need to put extra conditions on R or M to make the above statements true? From what I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921881/questions-regarding-modules-with-short-finite-length?rq=1), maybe I need In addition that all composition factors are pairwise non isomorphic? Thanks!

**My attempt at a solution**

1. For 1, we could induct on the length $n$. The statement is clearly true for $n=1,n=2$. So suppose that statement is true for $k< n$ and let $M$ be finite length $n$. Then since any two submodules have a nontrivial intersection, we know that $M$ is indecomposable, and so there can only be up to $n-1$ distinct propor submodules of length $n-1$, and (more generally, at most $C(n-1,k)$ distinct submodules of length $n-k$, althought not sure to show this). By the inductive hypothesis, each of these modules of length $n-1$ are cyclic. If there is only one such unique submodule of length $n-1$, then any element of $M$ not in that submodule would generate $M$. Now suppose there is more than one distinct submodule of length $n-1$. Assuming everything up to this point is okay,  here is where I am unsure. I think that $M$ should be cyclic and can be generated by a vector that is the sum of generators for each of these up cyclic modules of length $n-1$. On the other hand, maybe that is wrong and you should take the sum of pullbacks of generators for each of each of the composition factors that could correspond to modules of the form $M/K$, where $K$ is a submodule of length $n-1$.

Comment: There is some inconsistency: $\mathrm{Soc} M$ being cyclic is not the same thing as consisting of only one simple module. As an example of this, look at $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So which one of these two conditions do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Does not hold: A bit involved (at least for my standards) example is as follows: take a local Gorenstein Artinian ring $R$. Then it holds that $\dim_k \operatorname{Soc} R = 1$ (where $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ is the residue field), and whenever $I$ is a nonzero ideal of $R$, we have $0 \neq \operatorname{Soc} I \subseteq \operatorname{Soc} R$. So one only needs to consider a non-principal ideal $I \subseteq R$ as a counterexample. (I will update this if I think of something more reasonable, i.e. less involved.) In more concrete terms, I think that 
   $$R:=k[X, Y, Z]/(X^2, Y^2, XZ, YZ, Z^2-XY), \; M=I=\mathfrak{m}=(X, Y, Z)$$
   fits into this picture.
2. This does not hold, and the counterexample is easier. Take $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Alternatively, if you don't want your socle to be even cyclic, you can take $M=R=k[X, Y]/(X^2, XY, Y^2)$. Then $\dim_k \operatorname{Soc}R=2$, and so the socle is $2$-generated, even though $M=R$ is clearly cyclic.
3. If I didn't make a mistake in 1., I guess you may use it to disprove this as well: just take $M:=R$, and then the ideal $I$ as described above gives you a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating counter example. For 1., what if I assumed that the composition factor $Soc(M)$ was not isomorphic to any of the other $n-1$ composition factors.  Or if I made an even stronger assumption that  all composition factors are pairwise non isomorphic?

Comment: Should I make a new question with that added assumption?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, athough it would probably help to attract some attention by posting a new question. I don't know the answer to your additional question, to be honest.

Comment: I was thinking about this counter example and the all the submodules up to isomorphism. In this example there I found there is a unique nonprime principal ideal in dimension 1, infinitely many prime principal ideals of dimension 2 of the form linear homogeneous $(f(x,y,z,xy))$ where atleast one of the $x,y,z$ terms is nonzero. Then in dimension 3 there was infinitely many prime nonprincipal ideals of the form $(f(x,y,z,xy,g(x,y,z,xy))$, a unique maximal nonprincipal ideal $(x,y,z)$ of dimension 4.

Comment: This is due to the fact that any ideal of the form $(a+f(x,y,z))$, $a\in k$ nonzero generates $R$. Since there is a unqiue irreducible module, all composition factors are the same.

Comment: @Nate If you are talking about the example in 1., there should be only one prime ideal, and that is the maximal ideal $(X, Y, Z)$. $R$ is an Artinian ring, so it is 0-dimensional (meaning that every prime ideal is maximal). Moreover, the fact that $(X, Y, Z)^3 \subseteq (X^2, Y^2, XZ, YZ, Z^2-XY)$ imples that (X, Y, Z) is the only maximal ideal of $R$, i.e. it is local (in fact, it imples that $R$ is local and Artinian).